Build failure in CodeBuild with node package download failure with HTTP 304
I have React project which is deployed using S3 and CloudFront. I use deployment pipeline which involves CodeBuild. It has been working fine until today when I started to see build failures. I use a buildspec.yml file for the build process which is configured to issue a npm install command to setup the build environment. Nothing has been changed which affects the build process. After investigation I found out that the download of one specific npm package is causing the issue. Following are the log entries of the offending package.
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssesc/-/cssesc-3.0.0.tgz 1738ms (cache skip) npm warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
This issue is not visible when the package is installed outside of the AWS environment. I even issued a npm cache clean --force command before the npm install command in the buildspec.yml. I have used both Ubutu and Amazon Linux distributions with no success. What could be the reason for this behavior which is only visible inside the CodeBuild?

This issue corrected itself after a day. So, it should be something internal in the codebuild environment.
